# JavaScript Regular Expression HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all html tags in a given string...not what's inside, just the tag itself. I'm using `/<.*?>/g` which works some of the time but randomly misses some.

```
// <h1>blah</h1> produces tags.length = 2
// <h11>blah</h11> produces tags.length = 1
// blah</h11> produces tags.length = 1

let ALL_TAGS = /<.*?>/g;
let text = '<h1>blah</h1>';
let match = ALL_TAGS.exec(text);
let tags = [];

while (match !== null) {
    tags.push(match); // push the match into an array
    text = text.replace(match[0], ''); // remove the tag from the string
    match = ALL_TAGS.exec(text); // find more tags
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?!

Comment: So for some context, I'm running this in Node (so now browser) - and I'm not actually interested in the DOM element itself...this purely string matching.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - there is no dom structure here. I could replace "<" and ">" with "[" and "]" and I would still have the same problem...it really doesn't matter what I wrap the words with...they don't represent a structure or something on screen, it's literally just a string.

Comment: Swap the matching with replacing approaches. Use a `replace` with callback method as replacement argument to collect tags and remove them, it will be much safer then, and easier since you won't have to track the `lastIndex`. See [**this JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gr8agquu/). However, when you have to deal with real *tags*, like in XML/HTML/etcML this will still not solve the issue completely.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I understand but that won't help me. I need to know where in there string that "tag" is found - hence why I'm using .exec() - it give me the index where that string was found in the input string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I need to know (and store) where the matched string is in the input string. Using exec, gives me that.

Comment: Not really a problem with a replacing approach: https://jsfiddle.net/gr8agquu/1/

Comment: Or subtract the match length from the lastIndex - https://jsfiddle.net/6epa1b80/

Comment: @LewisPeel then edit the question to say "I need the index(es) of a string where such-and-such characters occur". Node.js vs. Browser and string vs. DOM are totally a red herring here and your edits are likely to invite people to tell you you're doing it wrong (as you've discovered). Also note that nothing in your sample code looks like it's using an index...

Comment: @JaredSmith - I can totally understand that it was a red herring, I'm going to delete this a repost it...too many misunderstandings!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Comment: @Bugs Lot of people were confused about my actual intentions, so I decided to delete this post and start a new one but because people had already commented...I'm not allowed to do that. So while trying to edit my post I got lot of errors about code errors (even though there wasn't any code in there), trying desperately to figure out what was going on I typed some nonsense. If you can delete this entire post for me, that would be great!

Comment: @LewisPeel Thanks for replying, I appreciate it. I would first look at flagging comments which are no longer needed. It might even be worth using a custom flag on each comment so the mods know what you are doing. Unfortunately you can't just delete a question. It is against site rules (frustrating I know).